# Splitting merged data into columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing a column of the following format, where I have Vars separated by commas ordered by count, with their respective counts after the colon

`df1 <- data.frame(A = c('Var1:1', 'Var1:2,Var2:1', 'Var3:2,Var2:1'))`

| A |
| --- |
| Var1:1 |
| Var1:2,Var2:1 |
| Var2:1,Var3:1 |

I've separated these out with:

`df1_split <- data.frame(dplyr::str_split(df1, A, pattern = ":|,", simplify = TRUE))`

Which yields:

| X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Var1 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Var1 | 2 | Var2 | 1 |
| Var3 | 2 | Var2 | 1 |

As you can see, sometimes variables are in column X1, but sometimes they appear in column X3. So Vars are always in odd columns, and their counts from the `:` are always in the proceeding even column#

My end goal is to have a dataframe with columns in the format:

| Var1 | Var 2 | Var 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
|  | 1 | 2 |

I've tried using a function, for loop and case when for this, as I have 19 unique variable names in my original dataframe but they don't always appear in the same order.

```
fVARCOUNT <- function(x, y){`
  # x is df_split, y are the unique Var nanmes e.g. Var 1, Var 2
  df_mutated <- df_split
  # Loop over each unique variable
  for(i in y){
    df_mutated <- df_mutated %>%
    # Check if that variable is in one of X1, X3, X5 and get the value from the proceeding column if it is
    dplyr::mutate('{{i}}' := dplyr::case_when(X1 == i ~ X2,
                                X3 == i ~ X4))
  }
}
```

However, the result I'm getting is as follows:

| Var1 | Var2 | Var 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
|  |  | 2 |

It's as though `case_when` is not checking beyond `X1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c('Var1:1', 'Var1:2,Var2:1', 'Var3:2,Var2:1'))
```

#### Code

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(A,sep = ",") %>% 
  separate(col = A,into = c("name","value")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = value)
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id Var1  Var2  Var3 
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1     NA    NA   
2     2 2     1     NA   
3     3 NA    1     2
```

Comment: Looks like this works once I added `sep = ':'` into separate(). Thanks!